# How to clean dill?

Tags: herbs

I have some fresh dill. How can the 'leaves' be easily separated from the 'stalks'? Should they be separated (I think so, but what do I know)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you just want a little flavor added to a potato salad without too much texture.

- After swirling the stalks under water and shaking off excess drops, pat with kitchen paper or cloth (doesn't bruise easily).
- Pluck off small clumps of the hairy leaves from the tougher stalk; this is completely subjective as to how much stalk needs to be eliminated.
- Chop. The more stalk is removed, the courser/longer the chopping in general is—up to a cm long.
  Also, the more dill is added to recipe, the finer it should be chopped (avoid the feeling of eating grass).

if a good deal is used, then stir into the mayonnaise first; if it is just of a garnish quantity, then sprinkle on top of mixed pot salad.